# Is it compulsory to setup Application Center with SSL cert when downloading iOS app?

Tags: ios, deployment, ibm-mobilefirst

**Question:**

Is it compulsory to setup Application Center with SSL cert (e.g. startssl.com) when downloading iOS app?

**What have I tried:**

1st Try:

1) I didn't configure SSL cert and try to download the ios app using http and https link. (http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9080/applicationcenter/installers.html and https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9443/applicationcenter/installers.html)

2) Major setting in mfp server.xml,

```
<featureManager>
  <feature>ssl-1.0</feature>
</featureManager>

<httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint” host="*" httpPort="9080” httpsPort="9443" >


<keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" password="worklight" />
```

**Result/Issue**

Http: [image]

Https: [image]

2nd Try:

1) Import .p12 generated in startssl.com

2) And follow this guide to setup the necessary configuration: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/appcenter/t_ac_ssl_lib.html

**Result/Issue**

Couldn't connect to the https server after configuring server.xml and restarting the mfp server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For iOS, TLS 1.2 is required on the server, yes.
See here: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/appcenter/c_ac_ssl_config.html

> You can configure the Application Center with SSL or without SSL, unless you intend to install applications on iOS devices. For iOS applications, you must configure the Application Center server with SSL and enable the TLS v1.2 protocol.

Comment: By the way is the free ssl cert generated using startssl.com sufficient?

Comment: <ssl id="defaultSSLConfig" keyStoreRef="defaultKeyStore" sslProtocol="SSL_TLSv2"/>

Comment: As long as the CA certificate for StartCom (which issues the startssl.com certificates) is recognized by the iPhone as a trusted CA (which I am pretty sure it is), the free certificate should be fine for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks @patbarron. Will definitely try it out.